# Breaking space and time

Tags: riddle

Within the vast expanse above,
You can find some vegetables,
Clothing for the bold and mighty,
And a few figures of highest power.

Within the unstoppable progressing force,
One can expel or discharge from itself,
Notice a small, frowned upon, arachnid,
Or a simple object, needed for something else.

Combine both, and get a defining system for life,
From it, we can get a famous baseball team,
A substance used for binding, or made from meals,
A key, or a door, leading to true freedom,
Properties of surgical tools, or even open wounds,
Leading to a final site, a site of calm and rest,
Onto which some ornaments, embossing, and relief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the vast expanse above,

> space

You can find some vegetables,

> peas

Clothing for the bold and mighty,

> capes - for superheroes

And a few figures of highest power.

> aces - the highest cards

Within the unstoppable progressing force,

> time - its arrow progresses

One can expel or discharge from itself,

> emit

Notice a small, frowned upon, arachnid,

> mite - belongs to the class Arachnida

Or a simple object, needed for something else.

> item - credit Stiv

Combine both, and get a defining system for life,

> space-time

From it, we can get a famous baseball team,

> Mets - from New York

A substance used for binding, or made from meals,

> paste an adhesive, or food pastes such as tomato

A key, or a door, leading to true freedom,

> Esc on a keyboard, or escape

Properties of surgical tools, or even open wounds,

> aseptic - free from contamination or surgically sterile

Leading to a final site, a site of calm and rest,

> campsite - credit Stiv

Onto which some ornaments, embossing, and relief.

> [empaestic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/empaestic) - credit Stiv for the last two words as the length increments by one.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I have too, except rot13(zl fvzcyr bowrpg vf 'vgrz' naq zl svany fvgr vf 'pnzcfvgr'), considering that particular section seems to be increasing by a letter each time.

Comment: It just so happens that Stiv is correct, and considering this, you'd only be missing the final one: "Onto which some ornaments, embossing, and relief."

Comment: Stiv usually is correct - and I think has a much more complete answer - I can include with credit!

Comment: Feel free to include :) I haven't yet spotted the last one either if what you came up with here isn't the intention...

Comment: Er... There might have been a misunderstanding, Stiv (I believe) was telling you uvf svaq sbe gur "fvzcyr bowrpg" va Cnentencu 2 vf "vgrz", naq uvf svaq sbe gur "cynpr bs erfg" vf "pnzcfvgr"

Comment: Yes, recently realised something needs to be fixed for the last line - not sure what at the moment  - maybe someone can post a complete solution if I can't think of exactly what fits best.

Comment: Oh, the last line might be [this](https://www.lexico.com/definition/empaestic)!

Comment: @Stiv - that fits the structure perfectly! You could post your answer as it would have everything.

Comment: No need to go cluttering the post with another answer - just feel free to include :)

Comment: Good job you two! :)